# Traversing through HTML elements using jQuery to retrieve <textarea> contents

Tags: html, jquery

In my project, I have a table with a  cell in each row, defined as shown below:

```
<td onclick='openNotes()'> <div class='notes-popup' id='notesForm'><form class='notes-container'> 
<textarea name='reqnotes'>123</textarea></form></div></td>
```

How can I traverse through this structure using jQuery and grab the text inside the textarea?

Comment: You're showing a HTML code that uses some inline `openNotes()` without explaining what it does, no JavaScript provided, no minimal HTML sample to play with. Please, could you make a quick [edit]? It's hard to understand where you're stuck at exactly. Do you want that text inside that `openNotes()` on in a completely new function handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your textarea with its name attribute and use the `val()` method to get the value.

```js
$(function() {
  var reqnotes = $('textarea[name ="reqnotes"]').val();
  console.log('Value of reqnotes : ' + reqnotes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td onclick='openNotes()'> <div class='notes-popup' id='notesForm'><form class='notes-container'> 
<textarea name='reqnotes'>123</textarea></form></div></td>
```

Comment: Your answer helped me to get this to work with a minor change. I had to change the first line in the function to:  var reqnotes = $(this).closest("tr").find('textarea[name ="reqnotes"]').val();  This way I am able to get the reqnotes pertaining to the current row. I therefore accept your answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- Avoid using inline JS. It's hard to debug. JS should be all in one place, not dispersed around HTML files. Use **class names** or **data-*** attribute instead

Examples using jQuery and pure JavaScript:

```js
function openNotes() {
  const $textarea = $(this).find('[name="reqnotes"]');
  console.log( $textarea.val() )
};


$(".js-openNotes").on("click", openNotes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- inline JS is bad for health and debugging. Use .addEventListener() instead -->
    <td class="js-openNotes">
      <div class='notes-popup' id='notesForm'>
        <form class='notes-container'>
          <textarea name='reqnotes'>123</textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or without jQuery:

```js
const openNotes = (ev) => {
  const textarea = ev.currentTarget.querySelector('[name="reqnotes"]');
  console.log( textarea.value )
};


const ELS_openNotes = document.querySelectorAll(".js-openNotes");
ELS_openNotes.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", openNotes));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- inline JS is bad for health and debugging. Use .addEventListener() instead -->
    <td class="js-openNotes">
      <div class='notes-popup' id='notesForm'>
        <form class='notes-container'>
          <textarea name='reqnotes'>123</textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```